Why does the rest of the circuit go off when my new light switch is on?
I have one outlet, three lights and three switches in one circuit. One switch is Dalia rcl-153pnl dimmer. The problem is when the light with dimmer on, others outlets and lights go off. I attached two images with connections.



Can you provide us with photos looking squarely into the backs of the boxes involved please?

Thank you for the comment, the problem has been solved.

I believe your dimmer is usable as a 3way, but your circuit to the light it controls is not.
The black from the dimmer and the 2 other black wires should be tied together.
The red from the dimmer should be connected to the red in the box.
The red with white stripe should be connected to nothing and capped.
The green wire should be connected to the bare copper grounds (not shown).  If the box is metal and you know it is grounded, only then you can leave it unattached.


Thanks a lot. It works well with your advice. The metal box is grounded.
